# How to monitor an FTP upload directory in coldfusion without using event gateways?

Tags: coldfusion, directory, monitoring

Having spent a couple of hours coding an event gateway solution, I discover that they are not supported by CF standard edition. Buggerit! So back to the drawing board.

I can see how I can check the folder's dateLastModified attribute using cfdirectory and so I can run a scheduled task to see when a new file has been uploaded, but whats the best way of storing/comparing the file list so as to get a list of just the ones added since last check.

General hints/links appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that, for whatever reason, you can't use a gateway, the simplest soluition that springs to mind is to move files you've procesed to a separate directory.  Then, your scheduled task can just deal with files in the FTP directory itself.

Comment: And in the morning this occurred to me too, i think it was just the problem of having one approach seemingly thwarted that blocked the obvilious. Sleep is funny.

Answer (score 1):

> they are not supported by CF standard
>   edition

Are you still using CF7?  It has been supported by CF Standard Edition since CF8

Comment: +1 this is not well documented. Only place I've been able to find information is Adobe's ColdFusion product comparison matrix:  https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf9_feature_comparison_matrix_ue.pdf. There Event Gateways are marked as an "Enterprise Feature" in Standard Edition. This means requests to it, and other features marked as such, are sent to the Enterprise Feature Router (EFR) - where the EFR is another footnote at the end of the document. It appears EFR queues these actions into a single thread.

Comment: That confused me, who would have thought that an enterprise feature would be available in standard, Now I just have to test how a single threaded event gateway holds up to things.

Answer (score 1):

As @Henry pointed out, you can use an Event Gateway.

If you decide not to use that approach, I'd suggest a ColdFusion scheduled task. Most foolproof algorithm for that task is storing the results of the last `<cfdirectory/>` call either in a persistent scope - application or server - or writing it out to a database or file (e.g. WDDX). Reason to hold on to all this information, rather than just a timestamp, is handling situations where newly added or changed files do not take on the correct timestamp for whatever reason (system clock off comes to mind).

If you use a database to capture the data you could use a [MINUS/EXCEPT query in SQL Server or Oracle](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/07/sql-server-except-clause-in-sql-server-is-similar-to-minus-clause-in-oracle/), respectively, to determine what's new. Else you'll need to do perform some nested looping in ColdFusion over the old a new queries to generate the list of new files.